# Multithread program to update different parts of table with different cursors

Tags: java, sql, multithreading, db2, db2-400

I have a table of one million records. on a column of each record I have to do a math operation on java that takes a fair amount of time. To improve total time, I created  threads. If I create 10 threads, I make a query on each thread of 100.000 records by using a SQL offset and a first fetch so I end up operating in the whole one million along all the threads.

It does improve the processing. I have 12 free processors. But I realized that if I create for example 4 threads, it is much better than one thread (half the total time), but if I create 8 threads, the time is almost the same as 4 threads.

On each thread, I am using something like

```
Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection(...);
Statement stmt= conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
ResultSet rs= stmt.executeQuery("select COL from DATA OFFSET X FETCH FIRST Y");   
while(rs.next()){
    //do math stuff on col
    rs.updateString("COL", new_math_stuff);
    rs.updateRow();
}
```

I was wondering if having different cursors on different connection on different parts of the table, still can cause too much IO on the table, hence having more threads doesn't help, or if the problem might by somewhere else. (I have very limited profiling capabilities because I am working on a remote computer and to compile the code I have to send it to some guy to approve it and do it.)

Comment: If you're using the Oracle RDBMS, then extended SQL trace will give you the data you need to know where your app's time is going. What you want is a profile of your app including the RDBMS details.

Comment: I am using DB2 on a as400,  I updated the tag, sorry

Comment: The same goes for any RDBMS vendor, although the name of the "show me the trace of what my app is doing to the RDBMS" feature will vary. If DB2 doesn't have that feature, then you're stuck with guessing, intuition, and experience.

Comment: IBM i and Db2 for i both include considerable performance monitoring.  But it doesn't sound as if the OP would be in a position to use any of it.

Comment: Are you using commitment control?  100K changes in a single transaction is somewhat large.  If not using commitment control, but the table is journaled, you'll have extra disk overhead.